# how to count up to a specific number in javascript, fizzbuzz

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to solve a problem similar to the popular fizzbuzz or pingpong question. I already figured out how to write this portion of the code, however I also need to make a counter in which the user inputs their number and the page gives back 1 to the number they input, as well as the fizzbuzz/popcorn numbers. I think the code is something along the lines of

```
for (i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {...}
```

But I don't know how to combine this with my other code

```
var pingpong = function(number) {
 if (number % 15 === 0) {
   return 'pingpong';
 } else if (number % 5 === 0) {
   return 'pong';
 } else if (number % 3 === 0) {
   return 'ping';
 } else {
  return false;
 }
};
```

Sorry, I know this is a super beginner question, but I'm just starting out and am having a hard time figuring out how everything works together.

Comment: `for (i=1; i<=user_input; i++) { pingpong(i); }` Is this what you asking for?

Comment: To me it appears that you don't know how the features of the JavaScript language work. It will be difficult to answer such a question in a way that would be helpful to you and helpful to future users of the site, particularly because SO is geared towards programmers and enthusiasts who *already know how to program*. What you're looking for appears to be more along the lines of a beginner tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close. To read more about [JavaScripts loops](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp).

```js
var pingpong = function(number) {
 if (number % 15 === 0) {
   return 'pingpong';
 } else if (number % 5 === 0) {
   return 'pong';
 } else if (number % 3 === 0) {
   return 'ping';
 } else {
  return false;
 }
};

for (var i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
  var num = pingpong(i);
  // Just show it on the screen
  document.body.innerHTML += i + ': ' + num + '<br />';
}
```